# Find the limiting distribution of $\bar{X}=\frac{\sum X_i}{n}$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be identically distributed with mean $E[X_1]=\mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_1]=\sigma^2$. Assume that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_k, X_{k+1})\neq 0$ for $k=1,\dots, n$ but $\operatorname{Cov}(X_k, X_l)=0$ for $|k-l|\ge 2$.

Find the limiting distribution of $\bar{X}=\displaystyle{\frac{\sum X_i}{n}}$.

---

I cannot use the Central limit distribution. Is there another method to do that?

Comment: For $|k-l| >2$ or for $|k-l|\geq 2$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes. You are right. Thanks

Comment: $\bar{X}$ converges in probability to zero. Try using Chebyshev's inequality, and be careful when you are calculating the variance of $\bar{X}$. I think you will need to assume that $Cov(X_k,X_{k+1})$ is bounded by a constant for all $k$.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 I mean the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to mimic the proof of the weak law of large numbers in the i.i.d. under a finite variance. Here the difficulty lies in the fact that we do not have independence. Since $X_i$ has expectation $\mu$, we derive that
$$
\mathbb E\left(\left(\overline{X_n}-\mu\right)^2\right)
=\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j).
$$
Then we split this double sum according to the following cases:

- $i=j$, in which case $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=\sigma^2$;
- $\lvert j-i\rvert=1$: by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get something independent of $(i,j)$ (namely, $\sigma^2$) and $2(n-1)$ such terms;
- $\lvert j-i\rvert\geqslant 2$: by assumption, $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0$.

We thus infer
$$
\mathbb E\left(\left(\overline{X_n}-\mu\right)^2\right)\leqslant \sigma^2\frac{n+2(n-1)}{n^2}\to 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks! But the question is to prove the central limit theorem.

Comment: I mean the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X}$. Can we have the similar result that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)\to N(0, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: @Hermi. The limiting distribution of $\bar{X}$ is the point mass concentrated at $\mu$, i.e., $\bar{X}\to\mu$ in distribution, as proved by Davide. If you are interested in the *asymptotical normality* of $\bar{X}$, meaning $$(\bar{X}-a_n)/s_n\to\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ for some suitable choices of sequences $(s_n)$ and $(a_n)$, then you should have asked so just like in your second comment. Since the original question has been answered, it is not a good idea to modify the original question and render Davide's answer unrelated. Rather, you may post another question with this updated information.

Comment: As Sangchul Lee said: I interpreted the question as the study of the limit of the empirical  averages. The question about asymptotic normality is an other story and is, to my opinion, a very interesting question that should be asked separately.